# wp-clear theme functions are not working in single.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am facing a problem in wordpress wp-clear theme, single.php don't load navigation bar declared in header.php while index.php do. I have also included `<?php get_header(); ?>` at top of single.php. same problem like this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_header-call-not-working-except-in-indexphp ,
navigation section defined in header.php as:

```
<?php if ( get_option('solostream_show_catnav') == 'yes'  ) { ?>
        <div id="catnav">
            <div class="limit clearfix">
                <?php if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) { ?>
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container'=>false,'theme_location'=>'catnav','fallback_cb'=>'catnav_fallback','items_wrap'=>'%3$s')); ?>
                        <li class="rss-comments"><a title="<?php _e("Comments RSS Feed", "solostream"); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('comments_rss2_url'); ?>">Comments</a></li>
                    <li class="rss-content"><a title="<?php _e("Posts RSS Feed", "solostream"); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">Posts</a></li>
                    </ul>                

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <ul class="clearfix"><?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?></ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

**note:** actually it prints html in output like

```
<div id="catnav">

  <div class="limit clearfix">
<ul class="clearfix">

    <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="/"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is printing the nav bar-just not adding the nav items by the look of it

Comment: ya sure, it don't print menu item...

Comment: ya offcource it display correct on homepage, see here http://testseite4.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem arises from a plugin.

actually i got through this problem a while ago.

the plugin creating problem was "simply exclude".
this plugin created problem when i added some pages to be excluded form frontpage widgets. it only works if only searches is selected.

--> in your case it may be a different one.

Check your activated plugins.

Comment: you are right! MyReviewPlugin was disturbing it. thanks a lot.